# Display the numbers of lines that were changed between two files

Tags: diff

I have two files: A and its modified version B. Is there some convenient way to display the numbers of lines that were added or changed in B (so basically the + lines in diff output)?

The solution would be even better if it scaled to multiple files (I intend to use it on the output of git diff), displaying the result in a format like filename:line.

Edit: my current idea is to use `git difftool` with some shell script and diff with `--unchanged-group-format='' --old-line-format='' --new-line-format='%dn'` (or something like that); these options are not listed in the diff manual on my system for some reason.

Comment: Like the option `--stat`?

Comment: No, I want to display the line numbers, not the number of lines.

Comment: this? `| awk '/^\+\+\+/{ file=$2; next } /^\+/{ print file ":" NR }'`

Comment: `NR` is wrong as it is the line number in the patch not in the file a delta is needed